# combine two sql queries having each a with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got two queries who are doing the job for me but I would like to combine them to have the results in one table instead of copy past the results into excel.

First query gives me the number of users whose at least one subscription have expired per month in 2018:

```
    WITH UniqueUsers AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ValidTo) ExpireMonth, UserId
        FROM UserInAppPurchase 
        WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
    )
    SELECT ExpireMonth, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
    FROM UniqueUsers
    GROUP BY ExpireMonth order by ExpireMonth;
```

Second query gives me the number of users whose at least made one subscription purchase per month in 2018:

```
    WITH UniqueUsers AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth, UserId
        FROM UserInAppPurchase 
        WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
    )

   SELECT PurchaseMonth, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
   FROM UniqueUsers
   GROUP BY PurchaseMonth order by PurchaseMonth;
```

Actually the PurchaseMonth and ExpireMonth are the same.

My expected output is: 1st column: months of 2018
2nd column: results from first query
3nd column: results from second query

It is not a big harm to just copy the two results and combine them manually, but I am curious how to do it directly in SQL.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: edited my post with my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would unpivot the dates and just do aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH(dte) as mon,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ExpireUserId) as numExpiredUsers,
       COUNT(DISTINCT PurchaseUserId) as numPurchaseUsers
FROM UserInAppPurchase uiap CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (ValidTo, UserId, NULL),
             (PurchaseDate, NULL, UserId)
    ) v(dte, ExpireUserId, PurchaseUserId)
WHERE dte >= '2018-01-01' AND dte < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(dte) 
ORDER BY MONTH(dte);
```

No subqueries, explicit `JOIN`s, or CTEs are really needed for this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, you can join CTEs

```
 ;WITH UniqueUsers1
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ValidTo) ExpireMonth
        ,UserId
    FROM UserInAppPurchase
    WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
    )
    ,UniqueUsers2
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth
        ,UserId
    FROM UserInAppPurchase
    WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ExpireMonth
        ,COUNT(UserId) UserCount
    FROM UniqueUsers1 c1
    GROUP BY ExpireMonth
    ) First
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PurchaseMonth
        ,COUNT(UserId) UserCount
    FROM UniqueUsers2
    GROUP BY PurchaseMonth
    ) Sec ON First.ExpireMonth = Sec.PurchaseMonth
```

Comment: so let's assume I would like to do it for 2019. There I do have values in ExpireMonth but not PurchaseMonth since no purchase has been made yet. Now, when replacing 2018 with 2019 the results only showing January and February because the PurchaseMonth has no data yet. But how can I force all 12 months? So when nothing is to count in PurchaseMonth just show 0?

Comment: This query uses inner join, this means in case where PurchaseMonth and ExpireMonth differs (for example, there is 1 as PurchaseMonth and no 1 as ExpireMonth) the result query will not contain 1

Answer (score 0):

You can store each result in separate temporary table, for example create two temporary tables like this:

```
CREATE Table #ExpiryDates (ExpireMonth int, TotalUsers int)
CREATE Table #PurchaseDates (PurchaseMonth int, TotalUsers int)
```

And then store first query result into the temporary table #ExpirayDates

```
;WITH UniqueUsers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ValidTo) ExpireMonth, UserId
    FROM UserInAppPurchase 
    WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
)
INSERT INTO #ExpiryDates (ExpireMonth, TotalUsers)
SELECT ExpireMonth, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
FROM UniqueUsers
GROUP BY ExpireMonth order by ExpireMonth;
```

Second Query will be like this:

```
;WITH UniqueUsers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(PurchaseDate) PurchaseMonth, UserId
    FROM UserInAppPurchase 
    WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
)
INSERT INTO #PurchaseDates (PurchaseMonth, TotalUsers)
SELECT PurchaseMonth, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
FROM UniqueUsers
GROUP BY PurchaseMonth order by PurchaseMonth;
```

Finally, compine these into one query

```
SELECT p.PurchaseMonth MonthNumber, p.TotalUsers As UsersMadePurchases, 
       e.ExpireMonth, e.TotalUsers As UsersExpiredSubs 
FROM #PurchaseDates p
LEFT JOIN #ExpiryDates e
    ON e.ExpireMonth = p.PurchaseMonth
```

Result will be:

```
MonthNumber UsersMadePurchases  ExpireMonth  UsersExpiredSubs
4           1                   NULL         NULL
5           2                   5            2
6           2                   6            2
7           1                   7            1
8           1                   8            1
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use smth like this:

```
with months as 
(
SELECT  MONTH(ValidTo) as month_
FROM UniqueUsers
WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
union
SELECT  MONTH(PurchaseDate)
FROM UniqueUsers
WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
),

UniqueUsers AS
(
    SELECT MONTH(PurchaseDate) as ExpireMonth, 
           COUNT(UserId) UserCount
    FROM UniqueUsers
    WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
    GROUP BY MONTH(PurchaseDate)
),


UniqueUsers1 AS
(

   SELECT MONTH(PurchaseDate) as PurchaseMonth, 
          COUNT(UserId) UserCount1
   FROM UniqueUsers
   WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
   GROUP BY MONTH(PurchaseDate)
)


select m.month_, 
       u.UserCount,
       u1.UserCount1
from  months m
      left join UniqueUsers u
         on m.month_ = u.ExpireMonth
      left join UniqueUsers1 u1
         on m.month_ = u1.PurchaseMonth
order by m.month_;
```

But I'm not sure your `order by` clause is what you want. Your months will be sorted as 1, 11, 12. Maybe you wanted another order, I just rewrote your queries in order to combine them.